# What's the minimum guaranteed substring match between a binary string and a chosen rotation?

Tags: combinatorics, binary, combinatorics-on-words, bit-strings

Given $n$:

- An adversary chooses a binary string $X$ of length $n$.
- I choose two distinct rotations of $X$, called $Y$ and $Z$, with the goal of maximizing $m$, the length of the longest prefix shared by $Y$ and $Z$. (By distinct rotations, I mean $Y$ and $Z$ shift $X$ by different amounts.)

Questions:

1. What's the minimum $m$ I can guarantee, as a function of $n$?
2. What's the adversary's strategy for choosing $X$ given $n$?

Weak choices of $X$ would be:

- A string of $n$ $0$s. For any $Y$ and $Z$ I pick, $m=n$.
- A Christoffel word (eg, $11011010$) that spreads $1$s pseudo-evenly among $0$s. For carefully-chosen $Y$ and $Z$ (eg, $10110101$ and $10110110$), all but the last two bits will match, $m=n-2$.

I'm looking for the strongest choice of $X$, with a corresponding value for $m$. Clearly $m \geq 1$, no matter how $X$ is chosen; I imagine the adversary can prevent $m \geq \log n$.

Note: there is a 1983 biology paper (https://www.pnas.org/doi/epdf/10.1073/pnas.80.18.5660) that claims without proof that the "length of the expected longest" duplicate in a random string is O($\log n$). Here, I am looking for the worst case rather than the expectation, and I am allowing for duplicates that may overlap and may wrap around.

Comment: What is the source of this question? What did you try to solve it ?

Comment: You could choose $Y = Z = X$.

Comment: Fixed question to clarify that Y and Z are distinct rotations of X.

Comment: Source of question: If X is fairly repetitive (say 1101101100) , then it's easy to find two rotations with fairly high overlap. Likewise, if X is a Christoffel word, there are always two rotations with massive overlap (m=n-2). I'm interested in Xs that are more "random" (in the Kolmogorov sense).

Comment: You're looking for sequences with uniformly low *auto-correlations*. Another search term is *Barker codes*.

Comment: I believe $m<\log_2n$. For example, with $n=8$ the adversary can choose $X$ such that no 3-bit sequence is repeated: $11100010$ gives $m=2$.

Comment: Right, we'd want to show that for any $X$, some choice of $Y$ and $Z$ gives $m \geq \log_2 n$.

Comment: That is not possible, and my previous comment proves it. What you want to prove is that for *some* $X$, *any* choice of $Y$ and $Z$ gives $m<\log_2 n$

Comment: You're right. What's equally true for your $X$ is that $m<n$ or $m<n^3$. I'm looking for the largest $m$ that can be guaranteed. From your earlier comment, I think you propose $m = \log_2 n - 1$ in general.

Comment: Got it, the type of $X$ you propose appears to be a de Bruijn sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is a power of $2$, the adversary can do no better than choosing the de Bruijn sequence for $X$. In that case, I can choose $Y=X$ and $Z =$ a one-position rotation of $X$ (in either direction), in which case $Y$ and $Z$ have a shared prefix length of $m= \log_2 n - 1$.